# Stop eclipse from line wrapping?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-formatter

Is there a way to get eclipse to stop erasing existing line breaks?  If I have a method signature like this, I can't figure out how to get eclipse to leave it alone:

```
void foo(
    int arg1,
    int arg2,
    int arg3,
    int arg4)
{
    // ...
}
```

With various settings it will either collapse the arguments down to one line, or wrap them at some margin like this:

```
void foo(
    int arg1, int arg2,
    int arg3, int arg4)
{
    // ...
}
```

With "Wrap all elements, every element on a new line" it does preserve this whitespace, but it will ALWAYS wrap, which isn't what I want.  I'd like eclipse to apply formatting for indentation and braces and such, just without ever deleting (or inserting) any line breaks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The formatting of arguments is [an old subject](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.jdt/msg16799.html), but the one new formatting feature introduced in 3.5 is:

- [eclipse3.5M4](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/S-3.5M4-200812111908/eclipse-news-M4.html#JDT) "Formatter option to preserve user line breaks"

The Java code formatter can now optionally preserve user line breaks by not joining lines in code or comments.

For example, the wrapped lines of the return statement in following test case:

[image: before]
<sup>Example of Code to Format</sup>

will be preserved by the formatter when the "Never Join Lines" preference is used, and now produces the following result:

[image: after]
<sup>Coded Formatted with Never Join Lines</sup>

This preference can be configured on the `Java > Code Style > Formatter` preference page. See the `Never join lines` option on the `Line Wrapping` and `Comments` tab.

That may help, but otherwise there is not much new features on that front in 3.5.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Thank you for mentioning it. Fortunately, those pictures were easy enough to find back (in http://ftp.ntua.gr/eclipse/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5-200906111540/images/ for instance)

Answer (score 21):

When I used the 'format' feature in Eclipse on my Java code, it tended split or break my lines of code in various places to make sure the content would always fit to a certain width.  I found this to be less than optimal if you have a wide monitor.  I worked around this issue by doing the following:

In eclipse 3.5, you can open preferences and search for "Format" or select **Java**->**Code Style**->**Formatter** from the left menu.  The default profile is called "Eclipse [built-in]" and if you want to make changes to the Java Formatter you will need to copy it and **create your own profile**.  This can be done with the "New" button right below the profile name.

Once you have created your own Java Formatter in eclipse, make sure it's selected and hit the **edit** button.  There a lot of features in here you can customize, but to fix the wrapping issue I selected the "**Line Wrapping**" tab.  Under general settings you will see "**Maximum line width**:".  This numerical value is the max line length the formatter will work with.  I bumped my up to a more **reasonable size** for larger monitors such as **180** characters.  **Save and apply** that and return to your code.

When you next try to format a java file, the line wrapping should only happen if you are above the new max size.

Happy Coding!

Comment: I think that will cause Eclipse to combine a few short lines into one long line if they add up to less than 180 characters.

Comment: well, also on tab `Comments` inside properties of Formatter, can be useful to change `Maximum line width for comments` to the same value as `Maximum line width`.

Comment: Thanks, Its help me to come out of the over headach

Answer (score 10):

You can use comments to guide the formatter.

```
void foo( //
  int arg1, //
  int arg2, //
  int arg3, //
  int arg4)
```

will preserve the line breaks at the comments.

Answer (score 6):

Eclipse 3.5 supports this. (It hit release candidate a a few days ago, so could be worth checking out)