# Eclipse formatter split long String

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-formatter

Is there a way to tell Eclipse formatter that when a String is too long, it should split it with `+` to fit the maximum line width **automatically**?

For instance, if my max line width is 80, I'd like this:

```
String s = "This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long String";
```

to become something like this:

```
String s = "This is a very very very very very very very very very very very"
+ " very very very very very very very very long String";
```

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5398814/2551236

Comment: @Vihar Yeah, I know that (actually my line width is 100), but you are just avoiding the problem. What if I have a 102 length line, or 183 in the case of that post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This would mean changing your source code, not just white space.