# Eclipse formatter: can it ignore annotations?

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

Sometimes I want annotations on fields be in a single line and sometimes in a line each. Is there any way to make Eclipse formatter just ignore these annotations and leave the lines breaks just as I did?

Comment: This question was answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820908/how-to-turn-off-the-eclipse-code-formatter-for-certain-sections-of-java-code

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352599/how-can-i-make-eclipses-autoformatter-ignore-a-section-of-code

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you mean, but you break up lines for field this way:

```
String text = 
"cake" +
"more cake" +
"alot more cake";
```

This is also an option:
You can go to Properties -> Java code style -> Formatter -> Edit: Then there should be some tags to on/off.
Also include this line in your code:

```
/* @formatter:on */
```

Answer (score 0):

I think so. In Preferences go to Java - Code Style - Wrapper. Then edit your active profile, click "Line Wrapping" and then "Annotations - Element-value pairs". Then set the Line wrapping policy to "Do not wrap".

Comment: That will not do it... It will just leave all annotation on a single line - no matter how many there are :-)

Comment: Indeed, you're right. In that case, I don't think the formatter can ignore annotations..

Comment: I am having to use eclipse in a new project and its things like this that drive me crazy. I set my save actions (which is a great feature of eclipse) but now it screws up all the annotation formatting. I have no perfect solution yet but a partial solution is to change the save actions to only format the changed lines. Its a part way solution