# Need generic way for null check

Tags: java

I need a generic way for null check. I came up with a requirement.
This is my setter method for a class:

```
placeHolderValues.setCurrentAddressCountry(communicationSO.getApplicationDetailSO().getApplicantDetails().get(0).getAddressDetail().get(0).getCountry());
```

I want to set values in `placeHolderValues.setCurrentAddressCountry()` only when value is present. If any of the `getApplicationDetailSO()` or `getApplicantDetails()` or `getAddressDetail()` or `getCountry()` is NULL then I have to set NULL in `placeHolderValues.setCurrentAddressCountry()`. I have almost 30 such types of setter.

I need a common method to achieve the same.

Comment: I wonder if you are using java 8? Then try using Optional, it's a great solution for nullpointerexception and you also be able to provide default value if it's null.

Comment: So the problem is that your getter chain could result in NPEs and you don't want to check each call's result? In that case Optional would indeed be one option (no pun intendend) as huy already suggested.

Comment: I am not sure about why a simple null-check in the callee won't suffice, however I will note that your call is a god-call, which is a type of code smell and 30 different setters, that all do more or less the same, may tell you, that the code architecture is bad.

Answer (score 4):

A serious non-answer here: don't do it that way.

Using `getA().getB().getC().getD()...getTheThingYouWant()` is really bad practice. 
It is a clear violation of the [Law Of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

So besides the problem you run into (about checking null), such constructs are *really actually evil*. You see, the class using this code **must** know that an A has a B. And that B has a C. And so on. This directly couples this class with all classes A, B, C, ... and so on.

The *real* answer is to avoid such changing. If at all, you do `getA().getMeWhatINeed()`.

The only other alternative: **validate** your input data completely (in an upfront step), before going down such call chains.

Comment: Agree. As mentioned in the comments, this is a common type of code-smell, see god-line: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell

Comment: @Mär You are very welcome!

Comment: @Mär Agreed that this is sort of a code-smell, but probably not a "god-line" type. After all, the problem persists even if you split the line up into several lines, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10391406/1639625).

Comment: @tobias_k Afaik this is a god-line type, simply due to length and readability.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Optional.ofNullable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-) and repeatedly [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) the value into another, unless you encouter `null` on the way, and then get the final value [`orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) `null`.

```
var value = Optional.ofNullable(communicationSO)
        .map(x -> x.getApplicationDetailSO())
        .map(x -> x.getApplicantDetails())
        .map(x -> x.get(0))
        .map(x -> x.getAddressDetail())
        .map(x -> x.get(0))
        .map(x -> x.getCountry())
        .orElse(null);
placeHolderValues.setCurrentAddressCountry(value);
```

This still is not very pretty, but at least you do not have to repeat the different method calls. Some of those lambdas (`->`) could probably also be replaced with proper Method references. (`::`) Still, it's probably better than just wrapping the line into a `try` block and `catch`ing the `NullPointerExceptoin`.

Comment: That is neat. And you could actually drop the lambda, and use method references, right?

Comment: @GhostCat At least in some cases, but not for e.g. the `get(0)`.

Comment: i have almost 3o setters. i need a generic method for this

Comment: Makes sense. Obviously, the current approach is nicely readable.

Comment: @Ashwaniojha No, honestly. You *need* to understand that you are trying to fix a symptom. Meaning: you are in need for workarounds because your underlying design is far from ideal ...

Comment: @Ashwaniojha Well, I guess if by "generic" you mean "without rewriting all my code", then probably the easiest way would be to `try/catch` the NullPointerException. But that's one code-smell more, then (also catching any NPE that might occur within those methods, possibly hiding severe bugs).

Comment: @Ashwaniojha In fact, you could probably semi-automatically translate your exisitng code by replacing `.(` with `).map(x->x.(` in those parts of your code.