# Is it possible to LOG different messages based on which step null is encountered while doing nested null check with Optional and map

Tags: java, optional-chaining

I have a nested object which can return a `null` at any point of time.

Thanks to `Optional` and `map` we can now do nested calls without having to put `null` checks after every get.

I have a very unique requirement where I need to know at which step exactly did I encounter a null object for e.g. (Copied from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74047406/1787314))

```
Optional.of(new Outer())
  .map(Outer::getNested)
  .map(Nested::getInner)
  .map(Inner::getFoo)
  .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

How can I LOG a different kind of log message depending on when and where I encounter a null value?

The code below is not valid but I am just trying to explain how it might look like programmatically:

```
Optional.of(outerObject).else(LOG.error("Outer was null"))
  .map(Outer::getNested).else(LOG.error("Nested was null"))
  .map(Nested::getInner).else(LOG.error("Inner was null"))
  .map(Inner::getFoo).else(LOG.error("Foo was null"))
  .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Comment: You just want a log message, but not an exception. Is that correct?

Comment: Just interpose `.ifPresentOrElse()` with a null `Consumer` and a logging `Runnable` after each step of interest.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes thats correct

Comment: @user207421 Would you be able to share an example?

Comment: I would just write my own `LoggableOptional` or something like that for this. The built-in `Optional` isn't meant for this kind of thing.

Comment: @Sweeper You mean a custom Optional class which would allow to LOG incase a null is found half-way?

Comment: Yes. Write your own class that has a `map` that also takes a custom message.

Comment: @Sweeper That is definitely a good idea but problem is in my entire code base this edge case only happens once. Not sure if its a good idea to write a new class for handling this one scenario :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a one-off thing, I would write a helper method that "wraps" the method references. The wrapper would return what the wrapped function returns, but if the wrapped method returns null, it also logs a message.

```
private static <T, R> Function<T, R> withNullMessage(Function<? super T, ? extends R> function, String message) {
    return t -> {
        R r = function.apply(t);
        if (r == null) {
            Log.error(message);
        }
        return r;
    };
}
```

```
Optional.of(foo)
        .map(withNullMessage(Foo::getBar, "Bar is null!"))
        .map(withNullMessage(Bar::getBaz, "Baz is null!"))
        ...
```

Note that this does not handle the case where `foo` is null. If `foo` is null, this will throw an exception. To handle this, you can start with a definitely-not-null thing,

```
Optional.of("")
        .map(withNullMessage(x -> foo, "Foo is null!"))
        .map(withNullMessage(Foo::getBar, "Bar is null!"))
        .map(withNullMessage(Bar::getBaz, "Baz is null!"))
```

Or you can write your own `of` that logs nulls.

Another drawback of this is that it doesn't work with `flatMap`s. e.g. this does not work as you'd expect:

```
.flatMap(withNullMessage(Foo::thisReturnsAnotherOptional, "..."))
```

You would need another wrapper method to handle that case.

If you need this sort of thing a lot, it's probably worth it to write your own `Optional`-like type, whose `map` methods take an extra argument.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks a lot. Instead of using Optional.of, if I use Optional.ofNullable(withNullMessage(() -> foo, "Foo is Null")) - would that work?

Comment: @NickDiv  No, that's not what `ofNullable` does. You could do make an optional out of the wrapper, and then `apply`, `Optional.of(withNullMessage(x -> foo, "Foo is Null")).map(x -> x.apply(null))`. But I think that is not any better...

Comment: Makes sense. When I tried running it, i understood it better. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the required behaviour with some exception handling like this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outer outer = new Outer(new Nested(new Inner("value")));
//        Outer outer = new Outer(new Nested(new Inner(null)));
//        Outer outer = new Outer(new Nested(null));
//        Outer outer = new Outer(null);
//        Outer outer = null;
        try {
            Optional.ofNullable(outer).or(() -> throwEx("Outer was null"))
                    .map(Outer::nested).or(() -> throwEx("Nested was null"))
                    .map(Nested::inner).or(() -> throwEx("Inner was null"))
                    .map(Inner::foo).or(() -> throwEx("Foo was null"))
                    .ifPresent(System.out::println);
        } catch (NullValueException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static <T> T throwEx(String msg) {
        throw new NullValueException(msg);
    }
}

class NullValueException extends RuntimeException {
    public NullValueException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}

record Outer(Nested nested) {
}

record Nested(Inner inner) {
}

record Inner(String foo) {
}
```

Comment: You should define your own exception class -- otherwise *all* `RuntimeException`s thrown in that try block will be reported as a null!

Comment: That's a good point. I will update my answer.

Comment: @ODDminus1 Thank you for the answer, really appreciate it. This looks like it will work but I also feel like I am going back to old ways of handling Null Pointers which I guess is the only way in my situation.

Answer (score 1):

Following the algorithm of one-off error mentioned in previous Sweeper's answer we could implement as below.This will take care of corner null cases as well

```
    public static void clientMethod() {
        Outer validOuter = new Outer(new Nested(new Inner("s")));
        Outer nullNested = new Outer(new Nested(null));
        Optional.ofNullable(nullNested)
                .map(outer->eam(outer, Function.identity(),"Extracted value: Outer was null"))
                .map(outer ->eam(outer, Outer::getNested,"Extracted value:Nested was null"))
                .map(nested->eam(nested, Nested::getInner,"Extracted value:Inner was null"))
                .map(inner->eam(inner, Inner::getFoo,"Extracted value:Foo was null"))
                .ifPresent(System.out::println);
    }

    public static <T,R> R eam (T object,Function<T,R> extracter,String extractedValueNullMessage){
        if(object != null){
            R extractedValue = extracter.apply(object);
            if (extractedValue == null){
                LOG.error(extractedValueNullMessage);
            }
            return extractedValue;
        }
        return null;
    }
```